# Error " No DEX File Found" while generating apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, dex

I'm using Eclipse Android Neon, while generating the apk file of exported project I got an error message "No DEX File Found".
appreciate your help solving my problem.

[screen shot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJIvQ.png)

Comment: Just go to Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build -> [] Skip packaging and dexing... this and Reinstall all the things ! hope this will help

Comment: you are awesome man, thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah Buddy ! :) I just post this as answer !

Comment: Just mark my post as answer so that other person who have same problem get solution @megadeth

Comment: Sorry, I should have at least 15 reputation to evaluate and mark your post as an answer. thanks again

Comment: now you can do this :) cheers ! buddy

Answer (score 9):

Just go to Window > Preferences > Android > Build > [] Skip packaging and dexing... this and Reinstall all the things !

hope this will help ! Cheers !

Comment: For anyone wondering, on Mac, in the  1) Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Build

2) Uncheck the "Skip packaging and dexing ..." checkbox

3) Hit the "Apply" button

4) Hit the "OK" button

5) Then generate a signed apk

Comment: This lets the APK build, but then I get INSTALL_FAILED_DEXPOT when installing

Comment: Unchecking "Window > Preferences > Android > Build > [] Skip packaging and dexing" does not seem to help in my case with Eclipse Neon.

You need to build the project manually then export signed apk, but then you will get a debug mode enabled on the build config.